# Creating code with python/turtle to bounce turtle off the wall

Tags: python

I need to have the turtle bounce of the edges of the window forever and the only problem I am having trouble with is what to set the turtle forward to each time it hits a wall. By putting in any set number into forward it goes off screen in a matter of a few loops. What do I need to put into the forward function to make sure it only goes as far as the wall and "bounces"?

```
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()

# Create a turtle and name it bob.
bob = turtle.Turtle()
window.reset()
window.setworldcoordinates(-50,-50,50,50)
bob.left(1)
bob.fd(51)
bob.speed(10)
while True:
    xBob = bob.xcor()
    yBob = bob.ycor()
    print(xBob,yBob)
    if xBob <= -50: 
        heading = bob.heading()
        bob.setheading(180 - heading)
        bob.fd()
    elif xBob >= 50:
        heading = bob.heading()
        bob.setheading(180 - heading)
        bob.fd()
    elif yBob <= -50:
        heading = bob.heading()
        bob.setheading(180 - heading)
        bob.fd()
    elif yBob >= 50:
        heading = bob.heading()
        bob.setheading(180 - heading)
        bob.fd()
window.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question as written is vague and broad. Please add more details regarding your problem. How is the code you show not working for you? What *specific* thing do you want different?

Comment: Edited it and made it a little clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a `turtle` that bounces back and forth at sensible angles. There are a few questions buried in your post. First, instead of calculating distance from wall you can just keep moving forward by 1 until you hit a wall. This will be approximate; if you need it to hit the wall *exactly*, then you'll need to use a distance formula. Also, your logic for changing directions was off when hitting the top and bottom wall. I also made a few other changes, like making the x and y dimensions variables.

```
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()

# Starting parameters
MAX_X = 50
MAX_Y = 50
initial_angle = 5
speed = 10

# Create a turtle and name it Bob.
Bob = turtle.Turtle()
window.reset()
window.setworldcoordinates(-MAX_X,-MAX_Y,MAX_X,MAX_Y)
Bob.left(initial_angle)
#Bob.fd(51) No need for this
Bob.speed(speed)
while True:
    xBob = Bob.xcor()
    yBob = Bob.ycor()
    print(xBob,yBob)
    if abs(xBob) >= MAX_X: # Use abs() to capture both walls
        heading = Bob.heading()
        Bob.setheading(180 - heading)
    if abs(yBob) >= MAX_Y:
        heading = Bob.heading()
        Bob.setheading(-heading)
    Bob.fd(1)
window.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing some of that up, but when the turtle hits a corner it bounces out of control on the border of the window until it reaches the other side.